# In (ListChangeListener.Change<? extends Classname> change) what is the use of "?" in it?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I was taking tutorial on filtering data on table view JAVAFX and saw that line 
its a listener and want to know what is the work of that "?" at that place?

Comment: Sorry i m new to javafx and i dont have that deep knowledge to search like you do ,

Comment: i just saw ? and search it over but i did't get any answer.

Comment: so i decided to ask a question.

Comment: Not a problem - it has just been answered before. Informally, `Change<? extends T>` means "Change of some unknown type, where the unknown type is `T` or a subclass of `T`."